# Flutter: Text overflow with String with '\n'

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show the effect of an overflow of text. But my long text cuts directly on a new line, '\n'. So instead of showing '...' it is just a blank space that cuts off, but there is actually more text, just that I wish for the user to expand it further to see more details.

Is there any known ways to do it? Or do I have to do my own check and just show ... when I find multiple '/n' in my string?

Edit: Sorry, for the late update.

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Text('Some text\nSecond Line\nThird Line\nFourth',                                                 
      maxLines: 3,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),)
```

This is what I get

[image: Result]

With the code above, the text 'Third Line ' just has a blank instead of 'Third Line...'

Is there anyway to get this result.

[image]

Second Update:
Sorry, not sure if it is already fixed. This is my Flutter and Dart versions

```
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f1875d570e (10 months ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

Third Update:
I used the AddReadMoreText Widget

```
child: Container(
  width: 200.0,
  padding:
      const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
      right: 10.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(
              15.0),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black
                .withOpacity(
                    0.2),
            blurRadius: 8.0)
      ]),
       child:AppReadMoreText('Some text\nSecond Line\nThird Line\nFourth',
              trimLines: 3,
              trimCollapsedText:'...',
              trimExpandedText:'...read less',
              style: TextStyle(),),),
```

I get this result

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code what you have tried till.

Comment: @gretal sorry for the late update, I totally forgot about this tread, so sorry. Cause I just gave up and just replaced all '\n' with a space. I appreciate you taking the time to help. sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Create a new widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum TrimMode { length, line }

class AppReadMoreText extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppReadMoreText(
    this.data, {
    Key? key,
    this.trimExpandedText = '\tread less',
    this.trimCollapsedText = '...read more',
    this.colorClickableText,
    this.trimLength = 240,
    this.trimLines = 2,
    this.trimMode = TrimMode.length,
    required this.style,
    this.textAlign,
    this.textDirection,
    this.locale,
    this.textScaleFactor,
    this.semanticsLabel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String data;
  final String trimExpandedText;
  final String trimCollapsedText;
  final Color? colorClickableText;
  final int trimLength;
  final int trimLines;
  final TrimMode trimMode;
  final TextStyle style;
  final TextAlign? textAlign;
  final TextDirection? textDirection;
  final Locale? locale;
  final double? textScaleFactor;
  final String? semanticsLabel;

  @override
  AppReadMoreTextState createState() => AppReadMoreTextState();
}

const String _kEllipsis = '\u2026';

const String _kLineSeparator = '\u2028';

class AppReadMoreTextState extends State<AppReadMoreText> {
  bool _readMore = true;

  void _onTapLink() {
    setState(() => _readMore = !_readMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle = DefaultTextStyle.of(context);
    TextStyle? effectiveTextStyle = widget.style;
    if (widget.style.inherit) {
      effectiveTextStyle = defaultTextStyle.style.merge(widget.style);
    }

    final textAlign =
        widget.textAlign ?? defaultTextStyle.textAlign ?? TextAlign.start;
    final textDirection = widget.textDirection ?? Directionality.of(context);
    final textScaleFactor =
        widget.textScaleFactor ?? MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context);
    final overflow = defaultTextStyle.overflow;
    final locale = widget.locale ?? Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context);

    final colorClickableText =
        widget.colorClickableText ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;

    TextSpan link = TextSpan(
      text: _readMore ? widget.trimCollapsedText : widget.trimExpandedText,
      style: effectiveTextStyle.copyWith(
        color: colorClickableText,
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = _onTapLink,
    );

    Widget result = LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        assert(constraints.hasBoundedWidth);
        final double maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;

        // Create a TextSpan with data
        final text = TextSpan(
          style: effectiveTextStyle,
          text: widget.data,
        );

        // Layout and measure link
        TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
          text: link,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
          maxLines: widget.trimLines,
          ellipsis: overflow == TextOverflow.ellipsis ? _kEllipsis : null,
          locale: locale,
        );
        textPainter.layout(minWidth: constraints.minWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth);
        final linkSize = textPainter.size;

        // Layout and measure text
        textPainter.text = text;
        textPainter.layout(minWidth: constraints.minWidth, maxWidth: maxWidth);
        final textSize = textPainter.size;

        // Get the endIndex of data
        bool linkLongerThanLine = false;
        int? endIndex;

        if (linkSize.width < maxWidth) {
          final pos = textPainter.getPositionForOffset(Offset(
            textSize.width - linkSize.width,
            textSize.height,
          ));
          endIndex = textPainter.getOffsetBefore(pos.offset);
        } else {
          var pos = textPainter.getPositionForOffset(
            textSize.bottomLeft(Offset.zero),
          );
          endIndex = pos.offset;
          linkLongerThanLine = true;
        }

        TextSpan textSpan;
        switch (widget.trimMode) {
          case TrimMode.length:
            if (widget.trimLength < widget.data.length) {
              textSpan = TextSpan(
                style: effectiveTextStyle,
                text: _readMore
                    ? widget.data.substring(0, widget.trimLength)
                    : widget.data,
                children: <TextSpan>[link],
              );
            } else {
              textSpan = TextSpan(
                style: effectiveTextStyle,
                text: widget.data,
              );
            }
            break;
          case TrimMode.line:
            if (textPainter.didExceedMaxLines) {
              textSpan = TextSpan(
                style: effectiveTextStyle,
                text: _readMore
                    ? widget.data.substring(0, endIndex) +
                        (linkLongerThanLine ? _kLineSeparator : '')
                    : widget.data,
                children: <TextSpan>[link],
              );
            } else {
              textSpan = TextSpan(
                style: effectiveTextStyle,
                text: widget.data,
              );
            }
            break;
          default:
            throw Exception(
                'TrimMode type: ${widget.trimMode} is not supported');
        }

        return RichText(
          textAlign: textAlign,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          softWrap: true,
          //softWrap,
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
          //overflow,
          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
          text: textSpan,
        );
      },
    );
    if (widget.semanticsLabel != null) {
      result = Semantics(
        textDirection: widget.textDirection,
        label: widget.semanticsLabel,
        child: ExcludeSemantics(
          child: result,
        ),
      );
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Now use it anywhere in the app like this.

```
 AppReadMoreText(
            'Your long string',
            trimLines: 2, // how many line show 
            colorClickableText: primary,
            trimMode: TrimMode.line, // another option is TrimeMode.length
            trimCollapsedText: '...read more',
            trimExpandedText: '\tread less',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyMedium!
                .copyWith(fontSize: 16, color: primary),
          ),
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if its the exact reason. But i think with the new line character it is affecting the way the TextPainter layout is being measured. I've updated the main question. can you take a look? So sorry, not sure if what I'm saying makes sense

Comment: Have you tried the above **AppReadMoreText** custom text widget? I think this is what exactly you want with ( ... read more ) options.

Comment: Hi ya, i tried it, it still doesnt show (... read more). Do I have to add all the same arguments? Cause I just used trimlines and style wich was required... ahh maybe i missed the trim collapsed text... my bad

Comment: I updated the third update that shows what I get from the AddReadMoreText Widget

Comment: @ChungHeon [ it's working fine ] (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xDQZLtIQGcfR6kF-7vPzbMWOtSEp7gVKQOcZG6rks8M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure mine is not working but i'm gonna assume its the only solution around. Thanks for the help.